# 'Bad Request' to Face++ FaceDetection API

Tags: c#, http, httprequest, face-recognition

I'm creating an app with Face Recognition and I can't call Face++ Face Detection API. What might be wrong in my request? It requires api key, api secret key and image file as byte array or as Base64 string. Landmarks and attributes are optional. I send a bitmap to the function **AnalyzeFace**, it works well, until the **client.PostAsync(url, content);**. As a response, it returns

```
Status code: 400, ReasonPhrase: 'Bad Request'
```

My code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WindowsForms
{
    class FaceRecognition
    {
        private const string apiKey = "MY_API_KEY";
        private const string apiSecret = "MY_PRIVATE_KEY";
        private const string attributes = "gender,age";
        private const string landmark = "1";

        private const int CONNECT_TIME_OUT = 30000;

        private static readonly HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        public static string AnalyzeFace(Bitmap bitmap)
        {
            byte[] image = ImageToByte(bitmap);
            string url = "https://api-us.faceplusplus.com/facepp/v3/detect";
            Dictionary<String,String> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();

            dictionary.Add("api_key", apiKey);
            dictionary.Add("api_secret", apiSecret);
            dictionary.Add("return_landmark", landmark);
            dictionary.Add("image_file",Convert.ToBase64String(image));
            dictionary.Add("return_attributes", attributes);

            try
            {
                CallApi(url,dictionary);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e);
                throw;
            }

            return null;
        }

        private static async void CallApi(string url, Dictionary<string, string> dictionary)
        {
            var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(dictionary);

            var response = await client.PostAsync(url, content);

            var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        }

        private static byte[] ImageToByte(Bitmap img)
        {
            ImageConverter converter = new ImageConverter();
            return (byte[])converter.ConvertTo(img, typeof(byte[]));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: My guess is either one of the headers or pieces of data provided is wrong.  Replicate your request using Postman and see what happens.

Comment: @ThePerplexedOne Man, you helped me a lot :D I checked headers one more time and saw that I was using a wrong key name

Answer (score 0):

`"image_file"` header is used for images with file format.
It should be changed into `"image_base64"`